# How to set Joi validations with custom messages?

Tags: node.js, joi

I was trying to set some validations with some custom messages in Joi. So, for example, I have discovered that when a string must have at least 3 characters we can use "string.min" key and associate this to a custom message. Example:

```
  username: Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(16).required().messages({
    "string.base": `Username should be a type of 'text'.`,
    "string.empty": `Username cannot be an empty field.`,
    "string.min": `Username should have a minimum length of 3.`,
    "any.required": `Username is a required field.`,
  }),
```

Now here is my question:

**Question**

```
// Code for question
  repeat_password: Joi.ref("password").messages({
    "string.questionHere": "Passwords must match each other...",
  }),
```

What method (`questionHere`) name need to set to `repeat_password` to be able to notify the user that passwords must match? I don't even know if `Join.ref("something")` accept `.messages({...})`...

*If someone could please show me some help in the Joi docs, I haven't find anything yet by there...*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are trying to find here is the error `type`. It can be found in the error object that the joi `validate` function returns. eg: `error.details[0].type` will give you what you are looking for.

Regarding your second question, `Join.ref("something")` doesn't accept `.messages({...})`. Here you can use `valid` in conjunction with `ref`.

eg:

```js
const Joi = require('joi');

const schema = Joi.object({
        username: Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(16).required().messages({
            "string.base": `Username should be a type of 'text'.`,
            "string.empty": `Username cannot be an empty field.`,
            "string.min": `Username should have a minimum length of 3.`,
            "any.required": `Username is a required field.`,
          }),
          password: Joi.string().required(),
          password_repeat: Joi.any().valid(Joi.ref('password')).required().messages({
            "any.only" : "Password must match"
          })
});

const result = schema.validate({ username: 'abc', password: 'pass', password_repeat: 'pass1'});


// In this example result.error.details[0].type is "any.only"
```

Comment: Perfectly, solved the problem! Thank you so much @Sahal !

Comment: I was struggling with `.ref(...).messages is not a function` error for some time. Solved my problem. I did not think of encapsulating it within `Joi.any().valid()`. Thank you so much!