# How can I set a standard message for Joi.ref?

Tags: reactjs, validation, error-handling, joi

I am currently using Joi validation for my project. The relevant values are price and maximum price, where maximum is optional but must be bigger than price.

I am using Joi.number().greater(Joi.ref('price')) for maximum price and I get the error: "maxPrice" limit references "ref:price" which must be a number when I leave price empty.

How can I set a custom message for this?

(I have read the documentation, but couldnt find anything that worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this link for answer [How to set Joi validations with custom messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65965707/how-to-set-joi-validations-with-custom-messages)?

Here is the answer copied from the link posted.

```
const Joi = require('joi');

const schema = Joi.object({
        username: Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(16).required().messages({
            "string.base": `Username should be a type of 'text'.`,
            "string.empty": `Username cannot be an empty field.`,
            "string.min": `Username should have a minimum length of 3.`,
            "any.required": `Username is a required field.`,
          }),
          password: Joi.string().required(),
          password_repeat: Joi.any().valid(Joi.ref('password')).required().messages({
            "any.only" : "Password must match"
          })
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).